# Draw circle near to box in tikz qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I'm trying to draw above a node:

1. a circle
2. Some text

[image]

But I dont know how to do it. This is my provisional code

```
\begin{figure}
\captionof{figure}{Estructura del análisis de árbol lógico }
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)-- +(0,-8pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\Tree [.{Modo de falla}
[.\node[draw]{Bajo condiciones normales \\ ¿Los operarios pudieron determinar que algo ocurria?}; 
[.Si [.\node[draw]{¿Este modo de falla \\ causo un problema de seguridad?};]
]
[.No [.\node[draw]{Falla oculta};]
]
]]

\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize,it}, width=\textwidth}
\caption*{Fuente: El autor.}
\label{fig:arbol_logico}
\end{figure}
```

And this is how it looks (looks terrible :) )

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tree using the original approach with [`tikz-qtree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionof{figure}{Estructura del análisis de árbol lógico }
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)-- +(0,-8pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\tikzset{
  every tree node/.style={
    draw,
    align=center,
    anchor=north,
    text width=5cm,
    font=\sffamily
    },
  level 1/.style={level distance=1.5cm},
  level distance=2.5cm,
  sibling distance=30pt,
}
\Tree 
[.\node[draw=none] {Modo de falla};
  [.\node (normales) {Bajo condiciones normales, ¿los operarios pudieron determinar que algo ocurría?}; \edge node[fill=white,near end,font=\sffamily] {Sí}; 
    [.\node (problema) {¿Este modo de falla causó un problema de seguridad?};
    ]
      \edge node[fill=white,near end,font=\sffamily] {No};
    [.\node[text width=3cm] (fallaocul) {Falla oculta};
    ]
  ]
]
\node[circle,draw,anchor=south east,font=\sffamily] 
  at ([yshift=6pt]fallaocul.north east) {D};
\node[anchor=south east,font=\sffamily] 
  at (normales.north east) {(1) Evidente};
\node[anchor=south east,font=\sffamily] 
  at (problema.north east) {(2) Seguridad};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize,it}, width=\textwidth}
\caption*{Fuente: El autor.}
\label{fig:arbol_logico}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to assign names to the nodes and then use those names to place the labels at the desired locations.

Comment: Nit-picking myself :) but it looks odd to me with just the two labels in serif and the rest sans.

Comment: Can't +1 again. :(

Answer (score 2):

Well... it is a tree, so I would recommend using `forest` which is really very, very good at trees.

Usually, I use sans serif fonts in diagrams but you can remove my tweaks if you don't like them ;).

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
{\sffamily\plstyle
\begin{forest}
  create my label/.style n args=2{
    tikz={\node [font=\small, thick, anchor=south east, inner xsep=0pt, #1] at (.north east) {#2};}
  },
  my label/.style={
    create my label={}{#1}
  },
  my circle label/.style={
    create my label={draw, circle, yshift=5pt}{#1}
  },
  for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    where level=0{}{l sep+=1em},
    thick,
    edge={thick, rounded corners=2pt},
    rounded corners=2pt,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    draw,
  }
  [Modo de falla
  [{Bajo condiciones normales\\¿Los operarios pudieron determinar que algo ocurría?}, my label={(1) Evidente}
  [ {¿Este modo de falla\\causó un problema de seguridad?}, edge label={node [pos=.75, fill=white]{Si}}, my label={(2) Seguridad}
      ]
      [Falla oculta, edge label={node [pos=.75, fill=white]{No}}, my circle label=D
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image: tree in forest]

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot manage the translation from English as well!

Comment: Just nit-picking: "ocurría" and "causó" with accents in the "i" and "o", respectively (I know they are missing in the OP's original text, but they should be there). "Evident=Evidente" and "Safety=Seguridad" ;-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina As I say, the translation is beyond me. Thanks - I've updated with your corrections.